# Adding Jwt HttpClient Handler with Blazor Asp.net Core 3.1.0 Preview 3

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-client-side

I recently upgraded my project from `Asp.Net Core 3.0` to the latest build `Asp.Net Core 3.1.0 preview 3`.

My project is running Blazor in the client, and I also intercept the pipeline to add a Jwt to the header of every request sent back to the server using my `JwtTokenHeaderHandler` which extends `DelegatingHandler`.

I add this in the `startup.cs` of my `blazor.client` project as follows;

```
        services.AddSingleton<HttpClient>(s =>
        {
            // Creating the URI helper needs to wait until the JS Runtime is initialized, so defer it.
            var uriHelper = s.GetRequiredService<NavigationManager>();
            var myHandler = s.GetRequiredService<JwtTokenHeaderHandler>();
            myHandler.InnerHandler = new WebAssemblyHttpMessageHandler();
            return new HttpClient(myHandler)
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri(uriHelper.BaseUri)
            };
        });
```

However, since the upgrade it appears that `WebAssemblyHttpMessageHandler()` is no longer available?

I cannot find any documentation as to how to fix this approach.

Can anyone advise on how I can correct this please?

**Update based on Aqua's answer**

After adding the following code to my `Startup.cs`;

```
        services.AddTransient(p =>
         {
             var wasmHttpMessageHandlerType = Assembly.Load("WebAssembly.Net.Http")
                 .GetType("WebAssembly.Net.Http.HttpClient.WasmHttpMessageHandler");
             var constructor = wasmHttpMessageHandlerType.GetConstructor(Array.Empty<Type>());
             return constructor.Invoke(Array.Empty<object>()) as HttpMessageHandler;
         })
         .AddTransient<JwtTokenHeaderHandler>();
```

Calling an `Authorized` Get endpoint from my `.razor` file;

```
var response = await Http.GetAsync<ContactTypeOutputModel[]>("ContactTypes/all");
```

(where the above is simply a typed wrapped service response using an extension method);

```
    public static async Task<ServiceResponse<T>> GetAsync<T>(
        this HttpClient httpClient, string url)
    {
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);

        return await BuildResponse<T>(response);
    }
```

I am still getting a 401 on the service? and no output logging to say the service is being used?

```
public class JwtTokenHeaderHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly IAppLocalStorageService _localStorage;     
    private readonly ILogger<JwtTokenHeaderHandler> _logger;

    private readonly HttpMessageHandler _innerHandler;
    private readonly MethodInfo _method;

    public JwtTokenHeaderHandler(IAppLocalStorageService localStorage, HttpMessageHandler innerHandler, ILogger<JwtTokenHeaderHandler> logger)
    {
        _localStorage = localStorage;   
        _logger = logger;

        _innerHandler = innerHandler;
        var type = innerHandler.GetType();
        _method = type.GetMethod("SendAsync", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod) ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot get SendAsync method");
        WebAssemblyHttpMessageHandlerOptions.DefaultCredentials = FetchCredentialsOption.Include;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogDebug("Adding Jwt to Header from JwtTokenHeaderHandler: SendAsync");
        _logger.LogDebug($"Does header contain 'bearer' token: {!request.Headers.Contains("bearer")}");

        if (!request.Headers.Contains("bearer"))
        {

            _logger.LogDebug("Adding Bearer Token to Header");

            var savedToken = await _localStorage.GetTokenAsync();

            _logger.LogDebug($"Saved Token is : {savedToken}");

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(savedToken))
            {
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", savedToken);
            }
        }

        //return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        return await (_method.Invoke(_innerHandler, new object[] { request, cancellationToken }) as Task<HttpResponseMessage>);
    }
}
```

Any ideas why this is not being hit?

Answer (score 1):

`WebAssemblyHttpMessageHandler` has been replaced by Mono's `WasmHttpMessageHandler` by you can't add a dependency to **WebAssembly.Net.Http**. 
To create a DependencyHandler for blazor WASM, I did a little hack :

```cs
    public class OidcDelegationHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        private readonly IUserStore _userStore;
        private readonly HttpMessageHandler _innerHanler;
        private readonly MethodInfo _method;

        public OidcDelegationHandler(IUserStore userStore, HttpMessageHandler innerHanler)
        {
            _userStore = userStore ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userStore));
            _innerHanler = innerHanler ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(innerHanler));
            var type = innerHanler.GetType();
            _method = type.GetMethod("SendAsync", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod) ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot get SendAsync method");
            WebAssemblyHttpMessageHandlerOptions.DefaultCredentials = FetchCredentialsOption.Include;
        }
        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(_userStore.AuthenticationScheme, _userStore.AccessToken);            
            return _method.Invoke(_innerHanler, new object[] { request, cancellationToken }) as Task<HttpResponseMessage>;
        }
    }
```

Is set it up in DI with:

```cs
return services
    .AddTransient(p =>
    {
        var wasmHttpMessageHandlerType =  Assembly.Load("WebAssembly.Net.Http")
            .GetType("WebAssembly.Net.Http.HttpClient.WasmHttpMessageHandler");
        var constructor = wasmHttpMessageHandlerType.GetConstructor(Array.Empty<Type>());
        return constructor.Invoke(Array.Empty<object>()) as HttpMessageHandler;
    })
```

The full code is [here](https://github.com/aguacongas/TheIdServer/tree/master/src/Blazor/Aguacongas.Blazor.Oidc)

Comment: Thats great many thanks for that but it still doesn't seem to be hitting my `JwtTokenHeaderHandler` and so my requests are being denied with a 401. I'll update the question with my steps.

Comment: Ok I have updated the question to include all updates codes. Thanks for all your help with this.

Comment: Hum, it looks like the `HttpClient` instance you use is not the one you setup in your DI. Did you try to create your client with `new HttpClient(JwtTokenHeaderHandler)' ?

Comment: No currently I just use the out of the box `HttpClient` in my .`.razor` i.e. `@inject HttpClient Http`. With previous versions it would then just intercept the pipeline. I have also added `services.AddHttpClient()` in the `Startup.cs`? (based on your repo link)

Comment: Do you mean from the `.razor` level or when setting up the DI in the `Startup.cs`?

Comment: in your .razor component